# How to setup SMS delivery for Zoho Writer Merge+Sign API

Tags: zoho

I'm using Zoho writer [merge and sign API](https://www.zoho.com/writer/help/api/v1/merge-and-sign.html) to send the document for signature,

Everything works fine except that I cannot find in the documentation how to enable EMAIL + SMS delivery nor the format for providing recipient phone and country code and the document is only sent via EMAIL.

I tried formatting the signer like below, but it doesn't even add the phone and country code to the contact created inside Zoho Sign.

```
[
    "recipient_1" => "test@email.com"
    "recipient_name" => "Test Name"
    "action_type" => "sign"
    "recipient_phonenumber" => "123456789"
    "recipient_countrycode" => "+61"
    "language" => "en"
]
```

Appreciate if someone can advise how to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want the send the document signature request via SMS? Could you please clarify what provider will you use to send it? I think you can use integration Zoho Sign with SMS provider to achieve that. And from there, you can use integration tool or create your own.

Comment: @SambadaBudiarga man, I think  you are not even familiar what is Zoho Sign, it has built sms capability

Comment: ah sorry, I just knew this feature. did not know that we can do this with Zoho Writer.